# Normalizing text using regex

Tags: python, regex, replace, text-mining, tweets

I am working with tweets and I would like to have all the variations of aa aaaa aaah ahhh replaced by a single expression 'ah'. However, using my code I also replace the single 'a' and the 'and' which I don't want to change.

```
a = 'trying a aa aaaaaa aaaah and aaaahhh aaaaaaaahhh '
re.sub('a+h*','ah',a)
```

This way i get:

```
Current output: 'trying ah ah ah ah ahnd ah ah '
```

But what I want is:

```
Desired output: 'trying a ah ah ah and ah ah '
```

Comment: You may use `{2,}` quantifer to match 2 or more occurrences. Adjust as you see fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current expression `a+` matches one `a` or more. You want the match to start with at least *two* a's.

```
s = 'a ah aah aa
re.sub('aa+h*','ah',s) # 'a ah ah ah'
```

This can be generalized with the quantifier `{x,[y]}` which matches `x` occurrences or more, optionally up to `y`.

```
re.sub('a{2,}h*','ah',s)
```